# Graph theory question

Tags: graph-theory

Here is an exercise from the book by Bondy/Murty that I am not quite able to understand.

> Show that every simple graph has a vertex $x$ and a family of $\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}d(x)\right\rfloor$ cycles any two of which meet only in the vertex $x$.

Comment: What is $d(x)$?

Comment: It's the degree.  I was confused before too but it actually makes sense

Comment: I was about to ask that too. I assume it's the degree of the vertex $x$. Assing that's correct: wouldn any vertex of minimal degree satisfy this?

Comment: @GregMartin: Oh that's probably it, but how can we prove it? I don't see how to apply the pigeonhole principle here.

Comment: Yeah, me neither. It's easy to get that many *edge-disjoint* cycles, but I'm having trouble seeing how to get *vertex-disjoint* cycles (which I think is what is being asked for).

Comment: @GregMartin: It's not necessarily the vertex of minimal degree. Let $K_5$ be the complete graph on $5$ vertices. Now consider two copies of $K_5$, and let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be vertices of the first and second copy, respectively. Add a new vertex $v$ and edges $(v,v_1)$ and $(v,v_2)$. Then $v$ has minimum degree (2) but no cycle goes through $v$.

Comment: @PedroMilet Thank you for the nice counterexample.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a solution without using the Pigeonhole principle...

Take the longest path $P$ in your graph $v_1 - v_2 -... -v_k$ (with all the vertices distinct).
Consider one of the endpoints, says $v_1$. All its neighbours must belong to $P$ (by maximality of $P$).

Let $v_{i_1},v_{i_2},...,v_{i_d}$ be its neighbours : $2=i_1<i_2<...<i_d\leq k$ and $d=d(v_1)$.

Now you have your $d'=\lfloor d/2 \rfloor$ cycles, meeting only in $x=v_1$:

- $v_1 -v_{i_1} - ... - v_{i_2} -v_1$
- $v_1 -v_{i_3} - ... - v_{i_4} -v_1$
- ...
- $v_1 - v_{i_{2d'-1}} - ... - v_{i_{2d'}} - v_1$

As it is in the Bondy and Murty's book, it is not clear that you can use the Pigeonhole principle and actually I have no idea on how you can use it here.

Comment: You are right, the hint about the pigeonhole principle was referring to another exercise... how embarrassing...

Comment: I am a bit confused. What is $v_1$? is it a terminal point of $P$?

Comment: Yes it is one of the endpoint of P

Comment: I don't see how we can guarantee that $d(v_1)>1$.

Comment: If not, then $v_1$ satisfies $\lfloor d(v_1) /2 \rfloor =0$ and there is no cycle containing $v_1$, hence $x=v_1$ is a solution.

Comment: Oh, of course, I get it now! I was making the problem harder than it had to be in my mind. Thank you!

Comment: @AlineParreau I think the question is meant to find a vertex $v$ with exactly $\left \lfloor {\frac{d(x)}{2}} \right \rfloor $ cycles, but your solution has $n-1$ cycles for vertex $v$.